How to load Vue component/form from JSON form schema
In my project I am receiving form schemas from the back-end that I want to dynamically display in the front-end. The form schema I want to try it with looks like this:
'{\n  "components": [\n    {\n      "text": "# Whats for Dinner?",\n      "label": "Text view",\n      "type": "text",\n      "layout": {\n        "row": "Row_0qhrhgs",\n        "columns": null\n      },\n      "id": "Field_1gcawnh"\n    },\n    {\n      "values": [\n        {\n          "label": "Chicken",\n          "value": "Chicken"\n        },\n        {\n          "label": "Salad",\n          "value": "Salad"\n        }\n      ],\n      "label": "Food",\n      "type": "radio",\n      "layout": {\n        "row": "Row_1w5annl",\n        "columns": null\n      },\n      "id": "Field_04ss86e",\n      "key": "meal"\n    }\n  ],\n  "type": "default",\n  "id": "dinner_form",\n  "executionPlatform": "Camunda Cloud",\n  "executionPlatformVersion": "8.6.0",\n  "exporter": {\n    "name": "Camunda Modeler",\n    "version": "5.28.0"\n  },\n  "schemaVersion": 16\n}'

This form schema is stored in a String variable. Are there any libraries that might help with loading the form or is there another approach?

Asking for libs is offtopic on SO. There's obviously no lib if this just some custom schema. Iterate the objects with v-for and output layout depending on the values, that's all
